# Access pending browser requests to backend with JS?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, client

Is it possible to view the pending http requests using JavaScript made by a browser, and operate on those requests?

For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://somehost.io/js/somescript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/somestyling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Content
    </div>
    <script>
      // Check pending requests here.
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Given the above HTML, I would like to see if the request to the remote host is taking too long, cancel the request if it is; or at least know if the request is preventing the page from fully loading.